# import contact to my website from gmail using access_token

Tags: google-contacts-api

I have access_token="#####"Client ID="#####"Client secret="##########"Project Number="#######"

Using Gmail contact API how to retrieve then contact list . I don't want to give credentials again . Because I already authorize the application and I don have  "access_token" provided by google . 
Also want to know in Class "RequestSettings" (google api) which one is Application name .
Please help.

I don't want to retrieve user contact list by providing User Id and Password .

Comment: I have same problem and looking for solutions.